# How to properly "include" an EJS file using node.js with express and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am starting to learn node.js, and have installed express and am using EJS with express.

I have the following code (mostly generated by express-generator):

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head><% include partials/head.ejs %></head>

  <body>
  <% include partials/header.ejs %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>

    <% include partials/footer.ejs %>
    <% inlcude partials/javascripts.ejs %>

  </body>
</html>
```

**javascripts.ejs**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My problem is that I am getting this error:

```
Unexpected identifier in /var/www/HomeWatch.com/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /var/www/HomeWatch.com/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs
    at Object.Function (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Template.compile (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:464:12)
    at Object.compile (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:288:16)
    at handleCache (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:147:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:350:14)
    at View.render (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at module.exports (/var/www/HomeWatch.com/routes/index.js:6:7)
```

It ONLY occurs when javascripts.ejs is included, if I remove it, the page loads fine.

This is my folder structure (I leave out what i don't think you need, but the entire express structure is there)

```
-bin
--www
routes
-index.js
views
-partials
--footer.ejs
--head.ejs
--header.ejs
--javascripts.ejs
-error.ejs
-index.ejs
app.js
package.json
```

Comment: Typo: `include` is misspelled. The `c` and `l` are swapped as `inlcude` for `javascripts.ejs`.

Comment: Oh man... That's ridiculous... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that renaming javascripts.ejs to javascript.ejs has solved the problem... I don't even have the courage to ask why...

Comment: But then changing it back again works too now... Forget I ever said anything... Must have been some hidden character that sublimetext was inserting.